# Find the matrix of the operator $f(T)$ relative to the ordered base of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension over the field $\mathbb F$.
$T$ is an operator on $V$: $T:V \to V$.
$B$ is an ordered basis of $V$.
The matrix $T$ relative to the basis $B$ is $A$.

If $f$ is an element of $F[t]$, find the matrix of the operator $f(T)$ relative to the same basis.

$$f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k.$$

Comment: Do you mean find the matrix of the operator $f(T)$ in the same basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $[T]_B=A$. Since $\left[T^k\right]_B=[T]_B^k$ for all integers $k\ge 0$, and 
$[\,\cdot\,]_B$ preserves linearity, we have
\begin{align}
[f(T)]_B=\left[\sum_{k=0}^na_kT^k\right]_B=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left[T^k\right]_B
=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left[T\right]_B^k=\sum_{k=0}^na_kA^k=f(A).
\end{align}